# How to cast from List<dynamic> to List<DateTime> in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, casting

I'm trying to convert a List<dynamic> to List<DateTime>.

I have this:

```
factory PredSche.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    print(parsedJson); //{values: [2021-09-06T11:00:00.000Z, 2021-09-08T13:00:00.000Z, 2021-09-07T11:00:00.000Z], name: first}

    var list = parsedJson['values'];
    print(list); //[2021-09-06T11:00:00.000Z, 2021-09-08T13:00:00.000Z, 2021-09-07T11:00:00.000Z]
    print(list.runtimeType); //List<dynamic>

    var listDates = list.map((date) => DateTime.parse(date)).toList();
    print(listDates[0].runtimeType); //DateTime
    print(listDates.runtimeType); //List<dynamic>

    return new PredSche(
        name: parsedJson['name'],
        values: listDates);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Declare `listDates` as `List<DateTime>` you have probably declared that variable with dynamic data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're letting dart infer the type of `listDates` and that together with simply calling `toList()` makes dart infer `dynamic` as a type argument for the variable `listDates`.
To solve this you can replace `var listDates = list.map((date) => DateTime.parse(date)).toList();` with `List<DateTime> listDates = List<DateTime>.from(list.map((date) => DateTime.parse(date)));`,
which should output this:

```
List<String>
DateTime
List<DateTime>
```